# Controller only connects to PC as an audio device

Tags: pc, ps4, controllers

My Dualshock 4 used to work perfectly fine and had been until yesterday. I would plug it into my PC and play, no problem. But now my PC only recognizes the controller as an audio device and not a game controller. I have researched about this problem and I found many people with similar problems but nobody's solution worked for me.

This is what the controller shows up as under the Bluetooth & Other Devices section of settings: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdklb.jpg

This is what my Device Manager looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/we2sI.jpg

These are the properties of the controller under Devices and Printers settings: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1mRg.jpg

Does anyone know of a fix for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You could try right clicking on it in Device Manager and selecting Properties

Switch to the Driver Tab

Click 'Update Driver'

Select 'Browse my computer for driver software'

Then 'Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer'

If you are lucky, the list of compatible hardware will include DualShock (or some form of generic controller perhaps) - which you can then select and click next

If you are not, you will have to untick the option and see if it is anywhere in the full list.

If there is a driver on there that matches the controller (which there should be in this case as it was working before), you should be able to find it in this list.

(I had to do this once for a 19in1 combo card that thought it was a joystick)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Just had this problem myself, after days of searching and nothing seeming to work I found this site.

https://github.com/nefarius/ScpToolkit/releases/tag/v1.6.238.16010

I installed the setup and selected to install dual shock 4 driver and to force driver installation, hope this helps.